# Loadrunner agents plan

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have to plan the agents(capacity and number etc) because our site will grow to 200+ servers within one month. My questions are below:

1. For one agent that is a real machine and this agent that has been divided into some virtual machines, which plan will lead to more load on servers?
2. How do I monitor agents that may be the bottleneck during performance tesing?
3. For each agent, what is the minimum configuration(CPU,memory etc)?

ps. All agents are Linux os. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am using LoadRunner Agents as Load Generator agents for the answer of this question.   If this is referring to monitoring then consider the agentless model which leverages SSH via BAC or Sitescope.

Optimally, use base hardware, not virtual machines.   You need to be very well; aware of all of the initial condition, hypervisor brokerage and timing record integrity issues if you go the virtual machine route.  You also need to disclose these well known issues with your test results as these impact integrity and repeatability of the tests.

Here is what I recommend prior to 12 which brings in 64 bit load generators

- Atom dual core 4GB, boot drive SSD, app and swap drive SATA3 10K or better.  If you are going to capture logs from your virtual users then you need that second drive array to be fiber channel connected with a raid array on the other end.   You will have delays in any case with logs
- With 64 bit load generation, Go for the fattest servers you can get.   A quad core Xeon with 32-GB GB of RAM would be great.   Same hard drive configurations apply here as to Atom based 32 bit load generator model

As far as number?   The number of servers is not the determinant factor, but the number of users and the weight of your virtual users in terms of resources per virtual user.   Depending upon your virtual user type, their weight and the size of a virtual user host you can potentially have 4-5K users per host.   Swap a few items on the type of virtual user and the resource fingerprint on a virtual user basis and you may drop that limit to as few as a couple of dozen.

At a minimum you are going to look at three load generators, one as a control group and two for primary load.   Getting to your question of how do I know if my load generators are coloring the results, well you should monitor your load generators in the same way as you monitor your application infrastructure.

The control generator will help significantly in this.   Going back to testing concepts, each test should include a control factor.  For performance testing you can include a set of virtual users for a reference application on every load generator at a fixed load and watch if those users degrade or you can include a separate control generator, hardware matched to the rest of the load generators, but includes a single virtual user of each type.

In the commingled, multi-app control model, if your control group of users degrades at the same time (unexpected) as your regular set of users then you will have a log generator induced delay in your test.    The expected model would be for your control set to run consistently throughout the test execution cycle.   For the control generator model if you have a degradation for your control group and your global group then you have a common source for the issue, the application of a common network.  If the control group does not degrade (or even gets a bit faster) while the non control group does, then you have a load generator induced issue on your performance times.

Your control generator should always be on hardware.  Why, because of the clock float issue on virtual machines, the varying initial and in test conditions, you need a reference sample to measure the skew imposed by the load generator model on virtual machines

Comment: Thanks for the detailed tips. BTW, can you shed light on:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457896/error-failed-to-send-data-by-channels-post-message-failed-in-loadrunner?

Comment: Not enough detail to provide an answer to the other thread.