# Error: Failed to send data by channels - post message failed in Loadrunner

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

I used LR for performance testing and encountered the below error:

Error: Failed to send data by channels - post message failed.

Does such error indicate agents number bottleneck? If so, I just need to add agents, right?

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you give more details on what you are doing, LR version, protocol type, what caused the problem. Giving us an error message will only trigger RTFM responses.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs on the Load Generator machine(s) when one of the threads under *lr_bridge.exe* that updates the eve files is not getting enough CPU time slice to be able to send events to the Controller. Enabling an additional flag in the mdrv.dat file on the LG machine will maintain the read and write threads for the eve files on the same main thread, thus allowing it to have all the CPU time needed.

**To fix this issue :**

Disable Web Diagnostics for J2EE/.NET. If the behavior remains, go through the next steps.

On all of the Load Generator machines where the Vusers are being executed, **edit the \dat\mdrv.dat file** by adding the line listed below in bold:

> [lr_trans_server]
>
> ExtPriorityType=transaction_server
>
> WINNT_EXT_LIBS=trans_server.dll
>
> WIN95_EXT_LIBS=trans_server.dll
>
> LINUX_EXT_LIBS=libtrans_server.so
>
> SOLARIS_EXT_LIBS=libtrans_server.so
>
> HPUX_EXT_LIBS=libtrans_server.sl
>
> AIX_EXT_LIBS=libtrans_server.so
>
> LibCfgFunc=TransactionServer_configure
>
> GetLoaderInterfaceFunc=get_ts_interface
>
> AddLoaderClientInterfaceFunc=add_ts_client_interface
>
> GetLoaderCommandLine=trans_server_extra_ext
>
> Loader=1
>
> ExtMessageQueue=0
>
> SecurityMode=On

**ExtCmdLineOverwrite=-eve_thread_run_on_main_thread**

Save the changes in the *mdrv.dat file* then re-run the load test.